# Powershell write in a Accessdatabase in specific fields

Tags: powershell, ms-access

We would to like write an "Enabled = False" in to a Accessdatabase from powershell.

This is the Script

```
$ts= New-TimeSpan -Days 90
$body=Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan $ts -SearchBase "*"| where Enabled -eq "True"| Get-ADUser -Properties *| select Name, Surname, Givenname, Lastlogon | Out-String
$Login=Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan $ts -SearchBase "*"| where Enabled -eq "True"| Get-ADUser -Properties *| select Name 
$database="\\***\RoleandRights.accdb"
$query="SELECT * FROM [QRY_USER]"
$Connection = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Connection"
$recordset=New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
$Connection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$database;")
$os=3
$lo=3
foreach($u in $Login)
 {
  $recordset.Open($query,$Connection,$os,$lo)
  $recordset.Fields.Item('ENABLED').Value = "FALSE"
  $recordset.Update()
  Set-ADUser $u.Login -Enabled $false
  Write-Host $u.Name "is disabled"
  $recordset.MoveNext()
  $recordset.Close()     
  }
$Connection.Close()
```

The script finds and deactivates any user whose accounts are idle for 90 days
We have an access database to manage user accounts.
The script should take out the hook in the case of the users, in the database, which are inactive.
The first line in the database is Enabled = false, but the rest is true

This is the Query

```
Jobfunction Login FirstName LastName Fon_Planned ENABLED CHANGED ID 
Test1 test1 Walter RacH 1000 true true 235 
Test2 test2 Hans Müller 2000 true false 2320
```

Comment: Why not: `$recordset.Fields.Item('ENABLED').Value = $false`. And what does "take out the hook" mean?

Comment: On each iteration, you're just opening the same query again, starting at the first row, and then disabling that first row. You probably need to add a `WHERE` clause to filter on the user you want to disable. However, without knowing your table structure, I can't say what it should contain.